# twitter4j - Count the number of tweets within 24 hours, return an integer

Tags: java, twitter, processing, twitter4j, twitter-search

I'm trying to retrieve a single integer of the number of tweets of a certain keyword within 24 hours.
So say the keyword is "traffic" I want to count the number of tweets with the word "traffic" within the past 24, and store it as a number, to be used to generate other things.

Right now I can provide a specific number using query.setCount and retrieve an arbitrary number(1024) tweets in the past 24 hours, but I have no way of telling if this is ALL the tweets within 24 hours, all I really want is a number, I don't need the actual text or other information of the tweets. Also, as new tweets come in, have that number update.

How could I go about doing this?

Here's my getNewTweets method so far:

```
    void getNewTweets(){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -24);

  String yesterday = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

Query query = new Query("traffic"); 
  query.setSince(yesterday);
  int numberOfTweets = 1024;
  long lastID = Long.MAX_VALUE;
  while (tweets.size () < numberOfTweets) {
    if (numberOfTweets - tweets.size() > 100)
      query.setCount(100);
    else 
      query.setCount(numberOfTweets - tweets.size());
    try {
      QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
      tweets.addAll(result.getTweets());
      println("Gathered " + tweets.size() + " tweets");
      for (Status t: tweets) 
        if(t.getId() < lastID) lastID = t.getId();

    }

    catch (TwitterException te) {
      println("Couldn't connect: " + te);
    }; 
    query.setMaxId(lastID-1);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell the exact count of tweets for a specific filter/search query,
Both the API's are rate limited.
You would have to use firehose to get all the tweets data and that is paid.

Below is an excerpt form twitter dev -

`Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is focused on relevance and not`    `completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to` `match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead`

Please read following links for more understanding on Streaming API's rate limiting -
https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-much-data-returned-when-using-streaming-api/8407

Answer (score 0):

That said (@mbaxi answer) I think that for a not really popular word the Stream API would be suitable for that task. I'm running this code for 5 minutes using the very popular "love" and got no warnings so far, also got about 25000 tweets in love...
I made this very simple and not precise timer just for the example sake... Although you said you don't want the text, it's is being printed to console...

Here an example

```java
import twitter4j.util.*;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.management.*;
import twitter4j.api.*;
import twitter4j.conf.*;
import twitter4j.json.*;
import twitter4j.auth.*;
int startTime;
int tweetNumber;
PFont f ;
String theWord = "love";


TwitterStream twitterStream;

void setup() {     
  size(800, 100);    
  background(0); 
  f  = createFont("SourceCodePro-Regular", 25);
  textFont(f);
  openTwitterStream();
  startTime = minute();
}  


void draw() {     
  background(0);
  int passedTime = minute() - startTime;
  text("Received " + nf(tweetNumber, 5) + " tweets with the word: " + theWord, 30, height - 50); 
  text("in last " +  nf(passedTime, 3) + " minutes", 30, height - 25);
}  



// Stream it
void openTwitterStream() {  

  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();  
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("-----FILL-----");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("-----FILL-----");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("-----FILL-----");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("-----FILL-----"); 

  TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

  FilterQuery filtered = new FilterQuery();

  // if you enter keywords here it will filter, otherwise it will sample
  String keywords[] = {
    theWord
  };

  filtered.track(keywords);

  twitterStream.addListener(listener);

  if (keywords.length==0) {
    // sample() method internally creates a thread which manipulates TwitterStream 
    twitterStream.sample(); // and calls these adequate listener methods continuously.
  } else { 
    twitterStream.filter(filtered);
  }
  println("connected");
} 


// Implementing StatusListener interface
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

  //@Override
  public void onStatus(Status status) {
    tweetNumber++;
    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
  }

  //@Override
  public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
    System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
  }

  //@Override
  public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
    System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
  }

  //@Override
  public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
    System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
  }

  //@Override
  public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
    System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
  }

  //@Override
  public void onException(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
};
```